# Get external URL and save to Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, urlfetch

I want to take a PDF URL and save it to Drive. The folder ID and URL are correct.

```
function uploadDoc(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('my_folder_id');
  var url = 'my_url';

  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var blob2 = blob.getAs('appl‌​ication/pdf');

  var newFile = folder.createFile('filename.pdf',blob2);
}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Exception: Converting from binary/octet-stream to appl‌​ication/pdf is not supported.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to fix two things:

1. After `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` you need to use the `getBlob()` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getblob). The `getAs('appl‌​ication/pdf')` method is not strictly required.
2. If you are using a blob, then you need to use the `createFile(blob)` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfileblob).

You are using the `createFile(name, content)` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfilename,-content) and in this method, `content` is string not blob.

Then to name of the new file, you'll need the `setName(name)` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setnamename).

```
function uploadDoc() {
  var url = 'https://www.gstatic.com/covid19/mobility/2021-02-21_AF_Mobility_Report_en.pdf';
  var foID = 'my_folder_id';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(foID);
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  var newFile = folder.createFile(blob).setName('filename.pdf');
}
```